# Configuring Web API Route Config

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an api action in my controller like below.

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/export")]
    public class ExportController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Report([FromBody]ReportInput input, string reportType)
        {
        }
    }
```

And I have added an configuration to my route config like this.

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{reportType}",
            defaults : new {reportType = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
```

But I cannot call my API url below. Which configuration should I do ?

`localhost:50773/api/export/report/InsuranceHandlingFiles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using [atttribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) already (in the form of `[RoutePrefix]`). You could switch to it completely. Instead of your current route configuration, you would simply do this:

```cs
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

And then, to map a URL such as `/api/export/report/InsuranceHandlingFiles`, add an additional `[Route]` attribute to your controller method:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/export")]
public class ExportController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("report/{reportType}")]
    //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                  add this
    public HttpResponseMessage Report([FromBody]ReportInput input, string reportType)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

If you want `reportType` to be optional, assign a default value to the `string reportType` parameter, and (if that isn't enough by itself), add a second route; e.g.:

```cs
[HttpPost, Route("report/{reportType}"), Route("report")]
public HttpResponseMessage Report([FromBody]ReportInput input, string reportType = null)
{
    …
}
```